# How to use grep to find *.part files in a directory

Tags: debian, shell, grep, regular-expression

Many a times I have a `youtube-dl` instance. When `youtube-dl` downloads files it does so in `*.part` files similar to how most file downloaders do (see e.g. https://www.file-extensions.org/part-file-extension).

The difference of course (and it is good) is that it downloads the media filename along with part etc. The problem is sometimes I forget the name of the `*.part` file. Now is there a way to parse through a directory and tell/share with me if there are any directories or sub-directories which have `*.part` files in them?

Comment: typically one would use `find` with a simple shell glob rather than `grep` ex. `find path/to/somedir/ -name '*.part'`

Comment: I don't want it be so big, it's in the current directory and I want to use something simple either grep or some other regular-expression which makes it easier to use globbing.

Comment: I suggested `find` because you specifically mentioned *"directories or sub-directories"*. If you just want to list the `.part` files in the current directory then a simple `ls *.part` will suffice

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command to find files matching certain criteria is `find`. If you want to search in the current directory, all you need is:

```
find -name '*.part'
```

To limit it to files only (no directories or any other type of result), use:

```
find -type f -name '*.part'
```

Alternatively, with `bash` you could do:

```
shopt -s globstar
echo **/*.part
```

The `globstar` option is explained in `man bash`:

```
$ man bash | grep -A3 '^  *globstar'
    globstar
        If set, the pattern ** used in a pathname expansion  context
        will  match  all files and zero or more directories and 
        subdirectories.  If the pattern is followed by a /, only 
        directories and subdirectories match.
```

Or, if you don't need recursion, if you only want the files in this directory and don't care about subdirectories, just do:

```
ls *.part
```

Comment: what is shopt globstar, could you elaborate that part a bit ?

Comment: @shirish it makes `**` look into subdirectories. See updated answer.